# socket.io how to make custom list of users

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

How to make a custom list of users connected to nodejs socket.io server? By custom, i mean that every user has properties like xPos, yPos, name. So that the list looks like this

`[ {xPos: 13, yPos: 42, name: "Example1"}, {xPos: 32, yPos: 53, name: "Example2"} ]`

also, I am NOT native speaker and my English is probably horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Index users by socket id
var ACTIVE_USERS = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('NEW_USER', function(user) {
    // Here user can have your custom properties (xPos, yPos, etc) that can be passed in from the client
    ACTIVE_USERS[socket.id] = user;
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    delete ACTIVE_USERS[socket.id];
  });
});

// You can get active users as an array this way
var users = Object.keys(ACTIVE_USERS).map(function(key) {
  return ACTIVE_USERS[key];
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Im getting error: ACTIVE_USERS.push is not a function

Comment: Thanks but I think that it should be a "socket.id" instead of "socket".